# Node.js npm error node-gyp

Tags: node.js, canvas, npm, easeljs

I have a big problem for install module with npm of node.js... I have install Python 2.7, visual studio 2010, 2012, 2013...
I search during a lot of days but it's impossible
I try with canvas but it's the same for all...

My error:

```
C:\Users\Guillaume\Desktop\Test>npm install canvas
/
> canvas@1.2.7 install C:\Users\Guillaume\Desktop\Test\node_modules\canvas
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Guillaume\Desktop\Test\node_modules\canvas>if not defined npm_config_no
de_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\n
ode_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Warning: Missing input files:
C:\GTK\bin\libfreetype-6.dll
Génération des projets individuellement dans cette solution. Pour activer la gén
ération en parallèle, ajoutez le commutateur "/m".
c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v120\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.R
edirect.props(44,3): error MSB4019: Le projet importé "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Platfor
m.Redirect.10.props" est introuvable. Vérifiez que le chemin d'accès dans la dé
claration <Import> est correct et que le fichier existe sur le disque. [C:\User
s\Guillaume\Desktop\Test\node_modules\canvas\build\canvas.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074
:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Guillaume\Desktop\Test\node_modules\canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "canvas"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! canvas@1.2.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@1.2.7 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the canvas package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls canvas
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Guillaume\Desktop\Test\npm-debug.log

C:\Users\Guillaume\Desktop\Test>
```